# How to solve this first-order linear differential equation $ty'+2y=t^2-t+1$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Initial value problem: $ty'+2y=t^2-t+1$ with $y(1)=1/2$, where $t>0$

This is as far as I got, before I proceed I want to make sure that it is in standard general solution form: $y'+p(t)y=g(t)$:

**General solution:** $y'+{2y \over t}=t-1+t1/t$

**Integration factor:** $\mu(t)=e^{2\ln t}$

Comment: Looks good to me. Keep going.

Comment: Use $e^{2\ln t}=e^{\ln t^2}=t^2$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 good eye, that simplifies things a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your differential equation (after multiplying throughout by $t$) can be written as
$$t^2 y' + 2ty = t^3 - t^2 + t \implies \dfrac{d(t^2y)}{dt} = t^3-t^2 +t$$
Hence, we get that
$$t^2y = \dfrac{t^4}4 - \dfrac{t^3}3 + \dfrac{t^2}2 + \text{constant}$$ i.e.
$$y = \dfrac{t^2}4 - \dfrac{t}3 + \dfrac12 + \dfrac{\text{constant}}{t^2}$$

Comment: Thank you, I got it from here ;).